# Is there a way to get the variant id from serialized Add to Cart Form in Shopify

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, liquid

currently I am using the standard POST /cart/add.js, Ajax call format, where I set my  `data: this.$form.serialize`. When I console log my serialized Add to Cart form, I see the entire form output with the ID  I wish to get the **variant id** alone however from the form. Is there a method to extract this piece of info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard form submit uses an input or select with a `name="id"` that is the variant ID that is submitted.

So you can target get the `variant.id` from that input or you can split the serialized output and get the id from there.

You can target it like so for example: `document.querySelector('[name="id"]').value`

Or if you like to get it from the serialized output you will have to split the string a little in order to get to the name:

```
var name = this.$form.serialize()
  .map(item => item.split('='))
  .reduce((result, item) => { result[item[0]] = item[1]; return result; }, {})
  .name
```